# Problems with left css triangle

Tags: css

I am trying to make a basic tooltip, but i am getting this weird outcome from the css triangle. 
**main.html**

```
<div class="max"></div>
```

**main.css**

```
.max{
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #da6262;
}
.max::before{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    border-color: transparent #fff;
    content: "";
    position: relative;
}
```

The outcome is [image: What am i doing wrong?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where you want to position your arrow, but try changing your `::before` property to `position: absolute`. By doing that, you take the `::before` (your arrow) out of the normal flow of the document, so it won't be constrained by the dimensions/padding of your element.

If you then want to position your arrow relative to your `.max` element, set `position: relative` to it. The `absolute` property positions relative to its first non-static element, in this case the `.max` element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1Lz27sj/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like a charm. You just solved all of my problems i had. Once again thank you so much.